# Is it possible to use AsciiDoc on VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asciidoc

I want to use AsciiDoc for documentation purposes and check the documentation into the Git repository next to the code. The AsciiDoc source files I want to be compiled to PDF during build and to be part of the build artifacts. Is there a plugin for VSTS, or a best practise for an on-premise windows build agent?

Comment: We are now using portable versions of the asciidoctor tools checked into our tools repo to execute generating our pdf and html in the build via a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

For Now, AsciiDoc is not supported for VSTS.

But there has related user voices suggest this feature, like [Add Preview for AsciiDoc (.adoc) files in addition to Markdown](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20325913-add-preview-for-asciidoc-adoc-files-in-addition) and A[dd support for asciidoc, particular for README.adoc like github has](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31873846-add-support-for-asciidoc-particular-for-readme-ad). And you can vote and follow up the user voices.

Another [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365715/add-preview-for-asciidoc-adoc-files-in-addition-to.html) to the idea page.

Comment: I'm afraid AsciiDoc doesn't have the critical mass necessary to get this done by voting on UserVoice. If MS implemented this, it could help with adoption of AsciiDoc.

Comment: The links are offline, can you please renew them?

Comment: UserVoice has been replaced. Users no longer have a voice? :)

Comment: Add support for AsciiDoc: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-Preview-for-AsciiDoc-adoc-files-i/365715?space=21&q=asciidoc